# C palindrome program working on local PC, but not on INGInious

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, palindrome

I have a c program that detects a palindrome. It also detects palindromes with spaces. It returns -1 if the string is null, 1 if it is a palindrome and 0 otherwise. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int pal(char *str){

    if(str[0] == '\0'){
        return -1;
    }else{
        size_t i = 0;
        size_t j = strlen(str) - 1;
        while(*(str + i) != '\0'){
            if(*(str + i) == ' '){
                i++;
                continue;
            }else if(*(str + j) == ' '){
                j--;
                continue;
            }else{
                if(*(str + i) != *(str + j)){
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }

        return 1;

    }

}


int main(){

    char *str = "a man a plan a canal panama";
    printf("%d", pal(str));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled and ran this program at my local machine, it worked fine. But when I uploaded it to a INGInious question of my CS course (INGInious is a platform where people can upload their answers about a specific topic and the system reviews it), it causes a Segmentation Fault. Is there any scenario that could lead to a SegFault that I am not aware?

Comment: This code is hard to read, but I would bet on the out-of-bounds access somewhere.

Comment: `*(str + i)` is the same as `str[i]`, which is much easier to read.

Comment: *It also detects palindromes with spaces.* – How is a palindrome containing spaces different from other palindromes?

Comment: @Felix it isn't modified.

Comment: Your `j` is being decreased uncontrollably. If it becomes 0, you are underflowing size_t (and it becomes huge number).

Comment: If the test string begins with a space then the `j` control is in trouble. But it compiles and runs on MSVC without any trouble and I can't see any other problem (apart from its efficiency - it should stop in the middle).

Comment: That's a good point, does OP know the test string that caused a failure?

Comment: code has undefined behaviour if the platform where you upload your code tests with  `str` being `NULL`...

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in my comments, you are not controlling for value of `j`, and because of that your code can potentially exhibit *undefined behavior* - when j becomes 0, but you keep decreasing it, it wraps around and becomes maximum value of `size_t` type (quite an impressive number on modern platform).

This does not happen with the string you provided, but, I imagine your testing platform tests it on another string (this is the only explanation I have for the crash).

For example, your code would be exposed to undefined behavior on following string: `"a   bcd"`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is way too complicated.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool is_palindrome(char const *str)
{
    size_t length = strlen(str);

    for (char const *front = str, *back = str + length - 1; front != back; ++front, --back) {
        while (isspace((char unsigned) *front) && front != str + length - 1)
            ++front;

        while (isspace((char unsigned) *back) && back != str)
            --back;

        if (front == back)
            break;

        if (*front != *back)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    char const *foo = "a man a plan a canal panama";
    printf("%d\n", is_palindrome(foo));

    char const *bar = "hello";
    printf("%d\n", is_palindrome(bar));
}
```

#### Output:

```
1
0
```

Answer (score -2):

In the loop below:

```
while(*(str + i) != '\0'){
    if(*(str + i) == ' '){
        i++;
        continue;
    }else if(*(str + j) == ' '){
        j--;
        continue;
    }else{
        if(*(str + i) != *(str + j)){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    i++;
    j--;
}
```

When `*(str + i) == '\0'`, it should be `i == strlen(str)` and `j == -1` (if no space in the string. Otherwise I am not so sure) and that might be the issue. But again, I can't really see you will not access `str` out of range. I would suggest to do this instead to make your loop easier to see the terminating condition:

```
while(i < j){
    // ...
}
```